# Is there any guarantees about the layout of std::map storage?

Tags: c++, dictionary, storage

Are there any guarantees about the layout of `std::map`? I know `std::vector` is guaranteed by the standard to have all objects sequential starting at `*vector.begin()`, is there any similar guarantee about `std::map`?.

Comment: Which real world problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @curiousguy: serializing a map of pod types to pod type into file. If it storage was like vector, I could just memcpy it all into a char stream. And I know it's safe because only the same program on the same machine will open the file.

Comment: "_And I know it's safe because only the same program on the same machine will open the file._" You answered my next question! ;)

Comment: Do you use `map` for performance? for code simplicity? Are you doing many insert/remove (relative to the number of lookups)? Depending of the usage pattern, you might benefit from using a `vector` rather than `map`. (The "contiguous storage" of `vector` guarantee would be a bonus.)

Comment: @curiousguy: I'm using the map for both performance and code simplicity. Using a vector instead will make lookup based on key complex (and used in many places), while copying the map to vector and serializing that is much simpler and used only once on program start and finish.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`std::map` is usually implemented as a Red-Black tree. Nodes are allocated from the heap as needed, so it's likely they end up in random places in memory. More formally, there's no layout guarantee in the standard.

Comment: I think it's guaranteed that each Key and its Value are stored as a `std::pair`, which has standard-layout.

Comment: Right on that. I meant no there's guarantee as to where different nodes are located in memory.